# Test equal group sizes

Tags: r, size, equals

How to test for equal group sizes in R?

`chisq.test(rep(1:3, 100))` yields 300 degrees of freedom, while I'd like this test to be performed with 2 degrees of freedom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chisq.test` expects tabulated data:

```
> chisq.test(table(rep(1:3, 100)))

    Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  table(rep(1:3, 100)) 
X-squared = 0, df = 2, p-value = 1
```